# Unity object detection without tags/layer 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find a way to make my healing ship shoot a laser and hit the target game object to heal it, but when it is on top or behind another game object, it obvoiusly uses their collider and terminates/heals that object, is there a way without tags and layers(using tags for another part of game) to make the laser only detect that game object or any other ways of doing it. Thanks in advance!

Code I currently use on building to detect the laser, with a tag.

```
 else if (col.gameObject.tag == "HealingLaser") {
        heal(col.gameObject.GetComponent<Laser_Heal>().healAmount);
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: well, using layers you can make the laser layer to only collide with the game object to heal layer

Comment: so if i have 2 healers with different objects, one can get stuck healing the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is another way without using layers and tags. Use interface.

Create an interface:

```
public interface IHealerLaser { }
```

Create a script that implements it then **attach** it to your *HealingLaser* GameObject:

```
public class ObjDetector : MonoBehaviour, IHealerLaser { }
```

Detect which Object collided with the interface:

```
IHealerLaser iHealer = col.gameObject.GetComponent<IHealerLaser>();
if (iHealer != null) 
{
        heal(col.gameObject.GetComponent<Laser_Heal>().healAmount);
            Destroy(col.gameObject);
}
```

---

If you just want to prevent two objects from colliding then use of the `Physics.IgnoreXXXCollision` functions.

Ignore collision between layer 9 and 9:

```
Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(9, 9, true);
```

or

```
Physics.IgnoreCollision(yourFirstCollider, yourOtherCollider, true)
```

To resume recognizing collision, pass `false` to the last parameter.